# ClientSocket is null after connecting socket client

Tags: c#

I use windows7 and VS2010 to write a C# winform  program.
In the program I run start a TCP socket server and a socket client. After the client socket is accepted, I send command to the client. 
When I send data, error occurs: `System.NullReferenceException.` at this line:

```
 myClientSocket.Send(bs3, bs3.Length, 0);
```

I have debug the program and the socket server and client could be created successfully. The client could also be connect to the server successfully.I think maybe myclientsocket is none so the command could not be sent. But I do not know why.
The code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public static Socket myClientSocket = null;
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    SocketServie();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    runclient();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    read();
  }

  public void SocketServie()
  {

    string host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 8024;
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
    SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);     //port reuse
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port));
    socket.Listen(100);
    Thread SocketThread = new Thread(this.ListenClientConnect);
    SocketThread.IsBackground = true;
    SocketThread.Start();
  }


  private void ListenClientConnect()
  {

    while (true)
    {
      this.clientSocket = socket.Accept();
      Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new
      ParameterizedThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));

      receiveThread.IsBackground = true;

      receiveThread.Start(this);
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
  }


  public void ReceiveMessage(object Form1)
  {
    Form2 f5 = new Form2();
    //Socket myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
    myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
    string InitCurMeter = "INIT_CUR_METER\r\n";
    byte[] bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitCurMeter);
    myClientSocket.Send(bs, bs.Length, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    string InitVolMeter = "INIT_VOL_METER\r\n";
    byte[] bs2 =
     Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitVolMeter);//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()
    myClientSocket.Send(bs2, bs2.Length, 0);
  }

  public void runclient(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      using (Process myProcess = new Process())
      {
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "socket_client.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-p 8024";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.Start();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {

    }
  }

  public static void read()
  {

    try
    {
      string readCurMeter = "READ\r\n";
      byte[] bs3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(readCurMeter);
      myClientSocket.Send(bs3, bs3.Length, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e5)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("read_cur error：" + e5.Message);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be to *separate* concerns. Why are *forms* involved in socket work? Secondly, we have mystery global variables like `myClientSocket` and the even more mysterious `socket` that I assume is also a global somewhere. Most servers should be written to expect multiple connections (even if that's just a reconnect after a previous disconnect from a single client) and you should wrap up that "connection" concept in a class that *owns* the relevant socket, tracks state, buffers, etc.